# Getting the right dictionary from delegate methods parameters

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type, watchconnectivity

I am wondering if this approach ensures that I am receiving the appropriate dictionary from the WCSessionDelegate method didReceiveMessage.

I am slightly confused with the uses of `if let _`, and have only come across the need to use this approach during this occurrence. What use cases is this approach for?

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    var dictionaryKey = "SomeKey"

    if let _ =  message[dictionaryKey] as? Bool { // receive sent over dictionary with a boolean value 
    // use dictionary information
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if let` pattern means _if the optional value does hold a value, pass in the unwrapped value for me to use_. Also, in this case it is followed by an underscore `_`, which means don't pass in (i.e. ignore) the unwrapped value. What your code is doing is checking if `SomeKey` exists in the dictionary, but ignoring its value (`true` or `false`).

Comment: hmm, definitely clarifies it! But regarding the selecting which `message` is being received, would this be the only approach since there are multiple messages being sent over at different times.

Comment: @paulvs so from what i understand is that this would be the best approach, just remove the cast so that I am jsut checking if the dictionary being received contains the key im looking for

Comment: If you just want to know that it exists, still do the cast as this will ensure a value of the correct type exists for the given key.

Comment: @paulvs ah okay, so just added security. Appreciate it!